# Simulating reliable sender and receiver on same machine using python

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7

New to python, I am trying to implement a sender and a receiver using python 2-7, I got the code figured out more or less but there are few things that still escape me and I can't find explanation that is simple enough:

```
while True:
      try:
      #...
      except:
          raise ValueError
```

I understood that this is a while loop that will execute the try code until an exception happens then the code under except is executed, but what is ValueError?

Another thing, in the try block I have this:

```
message, address = self.receive()
```

where:

```
def receive(self):
    return self.s.recvfrom(4096)
```

I understand that this receives data from the socket, the return value being a pair (string, address) where string is a string representing the data received and address is the address of the socket sending the data,
however what I don't get is that this line should execute instantly and the processor moves to the following one, so if the packet was not received exactly at the instant this line was executed how do we catch the packet? Is there some kind of buffer that saves received packets till this line executes or how does this work?

Thank you for your patience

Comment: This question is too broad. Within a single question, try to isolate one specific issue.

Comment: I knew that my questions would be easy for someone who is acquainted with python, so I thought it would be an overkill to ask each one alone, but you make a good point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question:

```
while True:  # an idiomatic infinite loop
    try:     # set up for try/except
        # do some stuff with sockets
    except:  # catch any exception
        raise ValueError   # catch-all error to say "there was a problem with that value"
```

Second question:

Yes, there is a buffer. `recvfrom(4096)` reads from that buffer up to 4096 bytes at a time. Note that the name of the first parameter [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvfrom) is *bufsize*.

Comment: So 4096 MUST be the frame size exactly, and this value should be agreed upon from sender AND receiver? and thank you so much ^^